# Determining Eigenvalue from differential equations

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $A$ be a real $2\times2$ matrix.
>
> A system of differential equations in matrix form is given in the form of:
>
> $$x'(t)=Ax(t)$$
>
> A particular solution to this system is given by:
>
> $$x(t) =\begin{bmatrix}
>         x_1(t) \\
>         x_2(t) \\
>         \end{bmatrix} =  \begin{bmatrix}
>         -\exp(5t)\cdot \sin(3t) + \exp(5t)\cdot \cos(3t) \\
>         -\exp(5t)\cdot \sin(3t) \\
>         \end{bmatrix}$$
>
> Let $\lambda$ denote an eigenvalue for A.
>
> Determine the real and imaginary parts of the eigenvalue that contains a positive imaginary part.

I'm not entirely sure about this and there's no answer in my textbook, so I'm asking here to make sure. Since the Eigenvalue is complex, the real and imaginary parts should be obvious since they are in the form of:

$$\Re(e^{\lambda t}\vec{v})=e^{\alpha t}(\cos(\beta t)\Re(\vec{v})-\sin(\beta t)\Im(\vec{v}))$$

$$\Im(e^{\lambda t}\vec{v})=e^{\alpha t}(\sin(\beta t)\Re(\vec{v})+\cos(\beta t)\Im(\vec{v}))$$

Thus:

$$\Re(\lambda)=5$$

$$\Im(\lambda)=3$$

Comment: You could always differentiate $x(t)$ to determine the matrix $A$ using your ODE and in turn deduce the eigenvalues to check.

Comment: Your intuition is correct.